# German to English word division

Tags: dictionary

I'm looking for a German to English dictionary which for example, when I search for the word "Wörterbuch", it shows:

> Wort: Word
>
> Buch: Book

Is there anything like this?

Comment: If you can't type *Umlaute* (äöüÄÖÜ) use *ae*, *oe* etc. The two dots represent an *e*. If you can't type *ß*, use *ss* instead.

Comment: Could you explain why - to what end - you need this?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann: I'm learning German and when I encounter a new word, for example "Sonderangebot", instead of just translating it to "special offer", I prefer to learn that it is actually "sonder-" + "angebot". In this way, I learn two new words and also, remember the meaning easier, because I understand the logic. I understand that the meaning is not necessarily the same, but it gives a very good clue. I have only found www.learnwitholiver.com that has this option.

Comment: To potential close-voters: I think "asking for a dictionary" is different from "asking for things found in a dictionary" - the latter being off-topic, the former being maybe a little open-ended, in the worst case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only dictionary that I found is: www.wiktionary.com which is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 6):

Such a dicitonary does not exist to my knowledge but you can easily get there with the wordformation browser offered from [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/index_en.html).

If you search for [*Wörterbuch*](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=W%EF%BF%BDrterbuch&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=en) click on the <kbd>Wordformation</kbd> button there. Then you are presented with an analysis as follows:

[image]

The blue entries are clickable, which means you can click on *Wort* and on *Buch* there. You will then not only find all other frequent composites built on these words but you will also have a link to a very concise German > English dictionary on the top right corner of the screen named [LEO (DE-E)](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/wort) for your convenience.

The search you are looking for is not displayed at once, but it is only two mouse clicks away, which is better than nothing. This can be done for many composites but as is the case for most dictionaries only the most frequent will be includes.

Comment: +1 for the link. Useful.

Comment: @Janka: Canoo is awesome !!!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a dictionary of German **stems**. Such dictionaries exist, but they aren't targeted to language learners but linguists.

But seriously, you don't need such a thing. Your goal is identifying the parts of a compound. There's an easy way to to that: understand the compound **from the end backwards**.

> Wörterbuch

- h ← that's for sure not a German word. Only vowels may stand alone.
- ch ← that neither, no vowel.
- uch ← that may be a German word, look it up. … No, it isn't.
- buch ← that's a German word. You know it well.

So … a *Wörterbuch* is a special kind of *Buch*. That's the logic behind German compunds. Let's check the rest.

- r ← no.
- er ← Ok, that's a German word. Let's stash it for now.

Continue with the rest

- t ← no.
- rt ← still no vowel.
- ört ← that may be a German word, look it up. … No, it isn't.
- Wört ← that may be a German word, look it up. … No, it isn't.

Hmm. No luck with *Wört*. It may be plural then. Plurals often have those pesky *Umlaute* in there. Look up *Wort* instead. YES!

BUT, the dictionary says the plural of *Wort* is either *Worte* or *Wörter*. So, the *er* we stashed is part of *Wörter*. We are done.

> Wörterbuch → book of many words.

---

This may seem tedious at first but believe me it works automatically as soon your vocabulary grows. Your lectures are built that way the compounds are made from words you already know. It's the same way German children learn the language.

---

If you are curious. There are some compounds which leave you clueless. And German speakers, too. For example *Staubecken*. This is either

> die Staub-ecken (multiple corners filled with dust)

or

> das Stau-becken (a basin meant to pond water)

Context is key then.

Comment: How do you know, what the OP _needs_?

Comment: Never claimed that. But I know what the OP **don't** need **to do** what he wants. And that, he described pretty spot-on.

Comment: Nimm's mir bitte nicht übel, aber für mich liest sich der Satz irgendwie bevormundend und von oben herab und ich bin mir relativ sicher, dass Du das nicht so meinst. Und darauf wollte ich nur aufmerksam gemacht haben.

Comment: Für mich liest er sich hingegen aufmunternd, so wie der ganze Text. So unterscheiden sich die Sichtweisen.

Answer (score 3):

Luckily there is one dictionary I know which provides you with this information. It's [**Larousse German/English** dictionary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2035410525). It separates the components of compound nouns by a vertical bar.

Examples:

> Wörter|buch
>
> Zahn|arzt
>
> Warte|zimmer

[Here is an example from inside the book.](https://www.rainbowresource.com/proddtl?id=007460)

Comment: Unfortunately Larousse refuses to load here (it may need registration). Do they also translate compounds separately? Can you give us an example/screenshot of how they work?

Comment: I put the link into your post. To see how it was made click on [edit]. I also added an Amazon link - SE has an affliliation with Amazon and will earn a little money for posting Amazon links.

Comment: Also see https://german.stackexchange.com/editing-help for all you can do while editing or writing posts.

Comment: But Mohammad wanted to get from *Wörterbuch* to *Wort* and *Buch*, not to *Wörter* and *Buch*. (For what reason ever he needs that.) So, the Larousse word division is not necessarily helpful.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Even if this division does not help him in some words, I am positive it will get him half the way. The other half can be done easily by most electronic dictionaries, because in such dictionaries you can put any form of the word (whether singular or plural) to get you automatically to the main 'singular' entery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are specifically any German to English dictionaries that do this, but most regular German dictionaries show the component words and there are special "Herkunfswörterbücher" (etymological dictionaries), that will give that information.